# Using ngx-json-viewer, I want to only expand certain nodes based on their name

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to pass an expression to the expanded property instead of a bool. The problem is that if I use a getter, I don't have access to the function context, only the context I declared the getter in.

This is what I'm trying to do now:

```
<ngx-json-viewer [expanded] = "expression"></ngx-json-viewer> 

expression = () => this.name == "multipleValues"
```

I'm also open to using other JSON viewers if this functionality is supported and there's no way of making it work with ngx-json-viewer.

Comment: Nobody understands your problem without code or a functional example (try stackblitz).